# React: Not able to write anything in the Textbox, not able to edit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to pre-fill the textboxes on page load with data in the list coming from api.
Now If user needs to modify the text entered in the textbox, editing textbox is not working. Not able to type anything in the textbox. Please check my code where I am doing wrong. TemplateName and TemplateDescr textboxes not able to type.

```
import React from "react";
 
export class Edit_Textbox extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                Template_ID: "",
                    TemplateInfolist: [],
                    TemplateName: "",
                    TemplateDescr:"",
                    }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       }

 

       componentDidMount() {

             if (typeof this.props.key_id !== 'undefined') {

                    const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;

                    if (Template_ID > 0) {

                           this.getProductTemplateInfo(Template_ID);

                    }

             }

       }

 

       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

             const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;

             if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {

                    console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);

                    this.getProductTemplateInfo(Template_ID);

             }

       }

       getProductTemplateInfo(Template_ID) {

             fetch(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })

                    .then(response => response.json())

                    .then((data) => {

                           this.setState({

                                 Template_ID: this.props.key_id,

                                 TemplateInfolist: data,

                                 loading: false

                           })

                           console.log(this.state.TemplateInfolist);

                    })

       }

       handleSubmit(event) {

             event.preventDefault();

                    const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;
                    const TemplateName = this.state.TemplateName;
                    const TemplateDescr = this.state.TemplateDescr;
 
         const data = {
                     Template_ID,
                    TemplateName,
                    }
                    fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
                           method: 'POST',
                           body: JSON.stringify(data),
                           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    })
                           .then(response => response.json())

                           .then((data) => {

                                 this.setState({

                                        ValidationStatus: data

                                 })

                           })

                           .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

                          .then(response => console.log('Success', data));

             }

 

       }

 

 

       render() {

             return (

                    <div>

                           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

<div>

       {

                                                                                             (this.state.TemplateInfolist.map((item, index) => {

             return (

       <table border="0" width="100%">

                                                                                         <tr><td>                                                                                  <input type="text" value={item.templateName} onChange={(ev) => this.setState({ TemplateName: ev.target.value })}  size="75" maxlength="150" />

<input type="text" value={item.templateDescr} onChange={(ev) => this.setState({ TemplateDescr: ev.target.value })}  size="75" maxlength="150" />
                                                                                           </td></tr>

                                                                                     

       <tr><td><button type="submit" onclick="ResetSession();">Submit</button>

       </td></tr>

</table>

       )

                                                                                             }

                                                                                             ))

                                                                                      }

       </div>

                                

                           </form>

                    </div>

 

             );

       }

}

 

export default Edit_Textbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not changing the same variable, in the value prop you have **item.templateName** (the same as **this.state.TemplateInfolist[x].templateName**) and in the onChange prop you have **this.state.templateName**

So, you have to modify this.state.TemplateInfolist in the exact position of the array, you should have an Id in the array to identify it ***(item.id)***.

I can propose this for the onChange prop in the input Text:

```
onChange={(ev) => {
     this.setState(prevState => {
          const TemplateInfolist = prevState.TemplateInfolist.map(info => {
              if (info.id === item.id) {
                    info.templateName = ev.target.value;
              }
              return info;
          })
          return {
              TemplateInfolist
          }
     })
     }
}
```

Just be sure that the fetched data has the ID in each item of the array.